# "install-templates-msvc.bat" cannot be found (VS 2012 express edition and Cocos2d-x ,Windows 7 64-bit)

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, game-engine, cocos2d-x

I just installed cocos2d-x.
I opened the "cocos2d-win32.vc2012" solution file and ran the projects successfully.
However i am not able to find the "install-templates-msvc.bat" file anywhere in the folder.

Where can i find this file..??

Comment: You cannot use template to create the project after cocos2d-x 2.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

install-templates-msvc.bat has been cancelled since v2.1.5.

To install the new version of cocos2d-x. You need use python to install it.

1. install python
2. download and unzip the sdk
3. enter \cocos2d-x-X.X.X\tools\project-creatory
4. in command line enter the command

> python create_project.py -project MyFirstApp -package com.yoyousoft.MyFirstApp -language cpp

-language option:cpp | lua | javascript

Then you can find the new project you created under \cocos2d-x-X.X.X\project\ folder.